# write() returns EINVAL, but I can echo, open, and read

Tags: c, gpio

I'm trying to write to a GPIO pin on an embedded platform, I've written code that reads the pin (successfully), and also tested by echoing to the file (successfully).

The minimal code that can produce this error:

```
static int write_gpio(int gpio_num, int data)
{
   char buf[50];
   int nwritten, file_desc;
   int attempts;

   snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio_num);

   file_desc = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
   if (file_desc < 0)
   {
       printf("Failed to open gpio %d value\n", gpio_num);
       return -1;
   }

   for (attempts = 0; attempts < 10; attempts++)
   {
       nwritten = write(file_desc, (void*) &data, 1);
       if (nwritten > 0)
       {
           break;
       }
   }

   close(file_desc);

   if (nwritten == -1)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "GPIO Write %d to %d failed\n", gpio_num);
       return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The read code is very similar, other than the way the file is opened and write() being replaced with read(). This code works. I can also do an `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio[n]/value` with success.

What's going on here? The manpage states that EINVAL is given when the file may not be writeable, but this file is clearly writeable, I've just done it with an echo command

Comment: How do you know that the error is `EINVAL`?  I don't see you testing `errno` anywhere, nor `perror()` nor `strerror`.  Also, in `fprintf(stderr, "GPIO Write %d to %d failed\n", gpio_num);` you have too few arguments and will get garbage in the second one.

Comment: couple of questions, is this machine big or littel endian, you will get different bits of data written in those 2 cases. Does data contain valid data, does gpionum contaian valid number? Note that your final fprintf is wrong

Comment: Yeah, a `write()` of 1 byte from an object of type `int` looks wrong.  Maybe it works if your machine is little-endian, but it almost certainly ought to be copied to `char` or `unsigned char` first.

Comment: Oh, wait, `echo 1 > file` works?  So that is writing the ASCII character `1` (0x31), not the raw byte 0x1 which is what would happen if you call your function with `data == 1` (assuming little endian).  What if you write the ASCII character `0` or `1` instead?  `write(file_desc, input ? "1" : "0", 1)`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good catch, maybe I need to write the ascii string 1? I'm not sure what the underlying driver is expecting. Good catch on the "writing an int" as well, I'll try both of those and report back

Comment: @NateEldredge It was indeed trying to write an int when an ascii character was required. Writing "1" (`1 + '0'`) was the solution

Comment: @NateEldredge The question is still open/unanswered. Should you make your last comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'll let @NateEldredge post the correct solution to the issue you are having. I just want to point out a second idea to solve the problem by using the `ioctl` function on the GPIO driver.

I find this solution more "C-ish" than opening the file descriptor and writing a string (cause I consider such approach more "command-line-ish"). The source for the following code can be found [here](https://blog.lxsang.me/post/id/33).

```
static int write_gpio(int gpio_num, int data)
{
   char buf[50];
   int nwritten, file_desc;
   int attempts;

   snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio_num);

   file_desc = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
   if (file_desc < 0)
   {
       printf("Failed to open gpio %d value\n", gpio_num);
       return -1;
   }

 
    // Set lines as OUTPUTS
    struct gpiohandle_request rq;
    rq.lineoffsets[0] = <DATA_LINE>;
    rq.lines = 1;
    rq.flags = GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT;

     

    ret = ioctl(file_desc, GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, &rq);

    close(file_desc);

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to line handle from ioctl : %s", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return;
    }

    // Write 1 to GPIO
    struct gpiohandle_data data;
    data.values[0] = 1; // HIGH offset 17
    ret = ioctl(rq.fd, GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, &data);

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to set line value using ioctl : %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    close(rq.fd);

   return 0;
}
```